# formFactory.form() doesn't exist ! PlayFramework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I've a little problem, i want to create a web app and i learn PlayFramework with java documentation of

This sample code :

```
public Result hello() {
    DynamicForm requestData = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
    String firstname = requestData.get("firstname");
    String lastname = requestData.get("lastname");
    return ok("Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname);
}
```

The ''formFactory'' doesn't exist.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeKRc.png

Why I don't have this field ?

And when i want to create a model, i don't have the model class

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hywdG.png

Thanks you so much if you resolve my problem ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaForms):

> To wrap a class you have to inject a play.data.FormFactory into your Controller

Play already knows about `FormFactory`, so just add a constructor parameter for it:

```
public class FooController {

    private final FormFactory formFactory;

    @Inject
    public FooController(final FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
    }

    public Result hello() {
        DynamicForm requestData = formFactory.form().bindFromRequest();
        String firstname = requestData.get("firstname");
        String lastname = requestData.get("lastname");
        return ok("Hello " + firstname + " " + lastname);
    }
}
```

I'm guessing the `Model` you mention is that of EBean.  You need to enable EBean for your project, and then you'll have the necessary classes on your classpath.

In `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

`build.sbt`:

```
lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

More information is available in the [relevant docs](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaEbean).

Comment: Thank's you for your answer but look http://i.imgur.com/z8nYVv1.png i d'ont have play.data package it's crazy ! :o

Comment: `FormFactory` is located in the core `play-java` jar.  Since you're using IntelliJ, you can easily check this by going to the bottom of the `Project` view, opening the `External Libraries` tree node and opening the `com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.5.x:jar` dependency. In there, you should find `FormFactory`.

Comment: I don't have a play-java[...] in External Libraries !! And when i want to add  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0") per example, i can't because my version of sbt is 0.13.5, i will updatade in 0.13.7, maybe the reason of the problem ? [link](http://i.imgur.com/DFT2huI.png)

Comment: How did you create your Play project?  If you use `activator new <project name>` and open the resulting `build.sbt` in IntelliJ, you shouldn't have any of these issues.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to import these 2 libaries in your Play Controller:

`import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.data.FormFactory;`

After that before using the Form Builder, inject it into your code:

```
@Inject FormFactory formFactory;
```

Your code should work fine after this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inject your formFactory like this:

```
@Inject FormFactory formFactory;
```

Comment: How ? And where, whit what dependency ? xD I'm confuse

Comment: Take a look at the constructor here: [link]https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.9/api/java/play/data/FormFactory.html

Comment: Why i cant't just do what it say in the example ?, i don't have play.data package in my app